# Problems with a game

Tags: python, game-development

I am a young Python programmer. I decided to create a 2D game using pygame Purpose of the game: Drive as much distance as possible on the car, without crashing into objects that will "spawn" during the game. The car will drive across the field.

I have problems with decoration sprites (during the game, trees will "fall" down on the edges of the window) Fig1.[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWChk.png)

So, trees should spawn right after the previous ones reach the middle of the window, but when new trees spawn, this is what happens to me: Fig2. And the game starts to freeze [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBxoH.png)

Here is my code:

```
from superwires import games, color
from random import randrange
games.init(screen_width = 530, screen_height = 600, fps = 60)

#Car sprite

class Car(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("C:/python/car.bmp")
    def __init__(self):
        super(Car, self).__init__(image = Car.image,
                                  x = games.mouse.x,
                                  bottom = games.screen.height - 10)
        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.yellow,
                                top = 5, right = games.screen.width/2)
        games.screen.add(self.score)
    def update(self):
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        if self.left < 65:
            self.left = 65
        if self.right > games.screen.width - 65:
            self.right = games.screen.width - 65

#Tree sprite

class Bush1(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("C:/python/bush.bmp")
    speed = 1
    def __init__(self, x = 20, y = 100):
        super(Bush1, self).__init__(image = Bush1.image,
                                   x = x, y = y,
                                   dy = Bush1.speed)
    def update(self):
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height/2:
            newbush = Bush1()
            newbush.__init__(x = 20, y = -100)
            games.screen.add(newbush)

class Bush2(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("C:/python/bush.bmp")
    speed = 1
    def __init__(self, x = 515, y = 100):
        super(Bush2, self).__init__(image = Bush2.image,
                                   x = x, y = y,
                                   dy = Bush2.speed)

    #Spawning new trees

    def update(self):
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height/2:
            newbush = Bush2()
            newbush.__init__(x = 515, y = -100)
            games.screen.add(newbush)

#Start
def main(): 
    road = games.load_image("road.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = road
    bush1 = Bush1()
    bush2 = Bush2()
    car = Car()
    games.screen.add(bush1)
    games.screen.add(bush2)
    games.screen.add(car)
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()

main()
```

I'll be glad to know where I made a mistake.

Used: Python 3.9, superwires, games

Comment: Are you getting any errors being outputted elsewhere? Also, it looks like `Bush1` and `Bush2` are the same class, and that you're using `__init__` in your `update` method in a weird way. `__init__` gets called when you instantiated a new object - calling it directly may lead to unexpected results. Similarly, since those classes rely on `games` being in the global scope, you may be running into reference issues - lacking them or overwriting them.

Comment: @NathanielFord i'm not getting any errors nowhere, just things in pic2

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two images.

Comment: Creating a new object automatically calls `__init__`.  You should be doing `newbush = Bush2(x=515, y=-100)`.  And, since those are the defaults, you don't need to specify them at all.

Comment: @TimRoberts check pics again pls

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem.  Once your first bush reaches the halfway point, you create two new bushes ON EVERY FRAME.  That's what you're seeing in your pic2 -- you have hundreds of slightly overlapping bushes.  You need to create a new bush only when the old one is EXACTLY at the halfway point, not AT OR BELOW the halfway point:

```
    if self.bottom == games.screen.height//2:
```

You might also consider deleting bushes once they fall off the bottom

Comment: This is exactly it - the erroneous output would totally happen due to this, as well as the freezing.

Comment: @NathanielFord I tried your code above. I'm getting an error at "update" method of class "Bush":   **"newbush = Bush(self.__image,"    "self.__image = games.load_image(image)"    "image = pygame.image.load(filename)    TypeError:  not a file object**

Comment: That doesn't look like Nathaniel's code.  It is probably time for you to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This may not address the specific problem you're running across, but it might help to unpack and zero in on what is happening.

Here you are creating a new `Bush1` and `Bush2` object:

```
bush1 = Bush1()
bush2 = Bush2()
```

Note that the code for these two classes are virtually identical. The differences are only in the `init` defaults. It is equivalent to doing this:

```
bush1 = Bush1()
bush2 = Bush1(515, 100)
```

It seems you have a misunderstanding, based on this, about how classes in Python work. This is reinforced by the two almost-equivelent-but-for-constants `update` blocks:

```
    def update(self):
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height/2:
            newbush = Bush1()
            newbush.__init__(x = 20, y = -100)
            games.screen.add(newbush)
```

On the third line of these blocks you're creating a new object. Then you're re-calling that objects `__init__` method. When you create a new object, a couple of hidden 'private' methods are run, the last of which *is* the `__init__` method. Typically if you need instantiation of an object to change, you would alter that method. You should never need to re-call that method.

Finally, you are not, so far as I can tell, actually moving the bushes. I suspect when you say 'starts to freeze' what is happening is you have many instantiations of the bushes overlapping one another, and the game is taking longer and longer to process each loop. Putting a print statement in each init method would probably help identify this problem, but it's possible your frameworks might have a better way to do that. (I am not familiar with them.)

Refactoring a bit to clean up the usage of classes and scoping variables properly should yield something along the lines of this (though almost certainly there is more we could do):

```
from superwires import games, color
from random import randrange
games.init(screen_width = 530, screen_height = 600, fps = 60)

#Car sprite

class Car(games.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, image: str):
        self.__image = games.load_image(image)
        #  Is the car really instantiated at the point the mouse currently is at?
        super().__init__(image = self.__image,
                         x = games.mouse.x,
                         bottom = games.screen.height - 10)
        #  Is 'score' really a field of 'car'?
        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, 
                                size = 25, 
                                color = color.yellow,
                                top = 5, 
                                right = games.screen.width/2)
        games.screen.add(self.score)

    def update(self):
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        self.left = 65 if self.left < 65 else self.left
        # This should probably be defined in a broader scope
        max_right = games.screen.width - 65
        self.right = self.right if self.right <= max_right else max_right 


class Bush(games.Sprite):
    speed = 1
    def __init__(self, 
                 image: str 
                 x: int, 
                 y: int):
        self.__image = games.load_image(image)
        self.__start_x = x
        self.__start_y = y
        super().__init__(image = self.__image,
                         x = x, 
                         y = y,
                         dy = Bush.speed)

    def update(self):
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height/2:
            # uses the same initial values as this object
            newbush = Bush(self.__image, 
                           self.__start_x,
                           -100)  # start vertically above the screen
            games.screen.add(newbush)

#Start
def main(): 
    road = games.load_image("road.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = road
    bush1 = Bush("C:/python/bush.bmp", 20, 100)
    bush2 = Bush("C:/python/bush.bmp", 515, 100)
    car = Car("C:/python/car.bmp")
    games.screen.add(bush1)
    games.screen.add(bush2)
    games.screen.add(car)
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: FYI, the sprites move automatically on each frame because of the "dy" parameter.

Comment: @TimRoberts That makes sense. Any chance the `update` method being provided is overriding the super classes' method and needs to call it either before or after it does everything else?